# Trying to read oplog, but got empty result

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to take a look at the oplog, so I downloaded mongodb-4.0.3 for Linux, created a config file:

```
replSet = rs0
dbpath = /data
```

And started mongodb with `./bin/mongod --config db.conf`, and initialize replication:

```
> rs.initiate({_id:"rs0", members: [{"_id":1, "host":"127.0.0.1:27017"}]})
{
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1599312413, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1599312413, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to created some collection:

```
use books
db.users.create()
db.users.insert({id:2, name: "whatever"})
```

But no oplog is available:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find()
```

What was wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `local` database

```
use local;
db.oplog.rs.find()
```